# Monte Carlo with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, montecarlo

I am studying OpenMP and need to implement it into the monte carlo simulation for estimating probability of consecutive kings in a Shuffled Deck. However, after I implemented it, the time taken still has not reduced as much as expected as shown in the picture. Is my OpenMP code used wrongly especially for 100000 and 1000000 times?  Thank for helping of possible and provide the code to help.

**Original code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

vector<string> org_deck = {
    "AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
    "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD",
    "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC",
    "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH"
};

bool KingQueen(const vector<string>& deck) {
    int n = deck.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if ((deck[i][0] == 'K' && deck[i + 1][0] == 'Q') ||
            (deck[i][0] == 'Q' && deck[i + 1][0] == 'K')) {
           
            return true;
        }
        if (i != n - 2 && ((deck[i][0] == 'K' && deck[i + 2][0] == 'Q') ||
            (deck[i][0] == 'Q' && deck[i + 2][0] == 'K'))) {
           
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false; 
}

//void ProgressBar(double progress) {
//    int width = 70;
//    int pos = static_cast<int>(width * progress);
//
//    cout << "[";
//    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
//    {
//        if (i < pos) cout << "=";
//        else if (i == pos) cout << ">";
//        else cout << " ";
//    }
//    cout << "]" << int(progress * 100.0) << "%\r";
//    cout.flush();
//
//}

void MonteCarlo(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    double seconds = 0.0f;


    cout << "Shuffled " << n << " times\n" << endl;
    //Start Time
    auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        vector<std::string> deck = org_deck;
        
        //Seed
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end(), default_random_engine(seed));
        if (KingQueen(deck)) {
            ++res;
        }
       
        if (i % (n / 10) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Progress" << (i * 100 / n) << "%" << endl;
        }

       /* double progress = static_cast<double>(i) / n;
        ProgressBar(progress);*/
    }
    auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>((end_time - start_time));
     seconds = duration.count() / 1000.0;
    printf("\nTime taken: %.3f seconds\n", seconds);

    /*cout << "Time taken: " << duration.count() << "seconds" << endl;*/

    /*cout << "=================================" << std::endl;*/
    cout << "Probability: " << static_cast<double>(res) * 100.0 / n << "%" << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
        MonteCarlo(pow(10, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**With OpenMP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> org_deck = {
    "AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
    "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD",
    "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC",
    "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH"
};

bool KingQueen(const vector<string>& deck) {
    int n = deck.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if ((deck[i][0] == 'K' && deck[i + 1][0] == 'Q') ||
            (deck[i][0] == 'Q' && deck[i + 1][0] == 'K')) {

            return true;
        }
        if (i != n - 2 && ((deck[i][0] == 'K' && deck[i + 2][0] == 'Q') ||
            (deck[i][0] == 'Q' && deck[i + 2][0] == 'K'))) {

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void MonteCarloOpenMP(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    double seconds = 0.0f;

    double seconds_openMP = 0.0f;

    cout << "Shuffled " << n << " times\n" << endl;

    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res) schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        vector<string> deck = org_deck;
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end(), default_random_engine(seed));
        if (KingQueen(deck)) {
            ++res;
        }

        if (i % (n / 10) == 0) {
            #pragma omp critical
            cout << "Progress " << (i * 100 / n) << "%" << endl;
        }
    }


    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("\nTime taken for OpenMP: %.4f seconds\n", end_time-start_time);

    cout << "Probability: " << static_cast<double>(res) * 100.0 / n << "%" << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
}

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
        MonteCarloOpenMP(pow(10, i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Without OpenMP]

[image: With OpenMP]

As you see, the time used will not be reduced but more than the time without using the OpenMP.

Comment: Your use of time stamps for initializing the rng looks very suspicious. Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70439041/how-to-make-this-code-thread-safe-with-openmp-monte-carlo-two-dimensional-integ/70439830#70439830 Notice how it initializes the rng only once per thread. It also gives you room to avoid copying the `deck` once per iteration. You can instead keep a thread-local copy and just shuffle that repeatedly

Comment: Your progress report is broken. You use static scheduling (which is the default, btw). That means thread 1 will get all `i` range `[0, n/threadnum`, thread 2 will get `[n/threadnum, 2*n/threadnum)` and so on.

Comment: Beyond that, something is wrong with your environment. When I test your code, it takes a fraction of a second, not over 100. And the progress report is out-of-order as expected from its broken design. Yours is in-order, as if compiled without OpenMP. And further, even with 1 thread, it should be extremely fast. Did you forget to enable compiler optimizations? Compile with `-O3 -fopenmp` if you use gcc or clang

Comment: @OP Any question concerning the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by the compiler options used to build the application.  The most important compiler option is the optimization setting used.  If you are running a "debug" build or an unoptimized build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Comment: @Homer512 because my project just wants to use the OpenMP to speed up the monte carlo simulation and the time used is the determination. In the whole program, I directly run in debug mode.

Comment: Random remark: you should not put a critical section with output in the timed loop. Remove that and your code will be much much much faster. You should avoid critical sections as much as possible. And you should *never* have I/O in a timed section.

Comment: Are you really compiling with the OpenMP flags (i.e. `-fopenmp` with gcc)? It's a classical mistake to forget that...

Comment: @Homer512 Good point about the progress report, and the fact that the ouput is ordered nonetheless raises serious doubts that the multithreading: it looks like the code runs with a single thread in all cases. The OP should definitely check that.

Comment: @Alexander Why the hell are you running in debug mode if you want to speed-up the execution? Sorry, but that's non-sense...

Comment: @Alexander *I directly run in debug mode* -- Then to be honest, you are wasting your time.  Run a release mode build.  And if the compiler is Visual Studio, you are *really* wasting your time running debug builds to do timing tests, since STL containers such as `std::vector` will do iterator checking and validation in debug builds, and those checks do not exist in release builds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually I already test many way to solve this probelm with running in debig mode and within cmd. However, the result remain same so maybe I think the OpenMP is not suitable for Monte Carlo Stumulation because it just reduce little time.

Comment: Did you miss where I wrote that I tested your code unchanged and it took fractions of a second instead of 100 seconds in your case? Your code is okay, it got issues but it works. It's your compiler setting and runtime environment that causes issues. There are three people in your comments telling you to change your compiler settings. Why do you ignore our advise?

Comment: @Homer512 Actually I really not understand what meaning for the suggestion. I just directly run the code in cmd by directly running the exe file. Sorry about that.

Comment: What is your compiler? How do you run the compiler? Paul asked that yesterday

Comment: @Homer512 Ok, I already know the problem. It works already. Thanks for asnwering my quesiton.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of textual output. Copy the text into a code block instead. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You re-initialize the random generator in each iteration. That is unlikely to give a good random sequence. Instead, make your generators threadprivate.

```
// global
static random_device rd; 
static mt19937 rng;
#pragma omp threadprivate(rd) 
#pragma omp threadprivate(rng)

// in main, do a parallel seed:
#pragma omp parallel
rng = mt19937(rd());

// anywhere in your program use rng in parallel:
#pragma omp parallel
 {
    stringstream res;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> percent(1, 100);
    res << "Thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << ": " << percent(rng) << "\n";
    cout << res.str();
  }
```

Comment: it mean the in main section place in the `int main` and the use section replace the seed part?

Comment: @Alexander If I understand you  correctly: yes. You should seed only once, which is done in the `rng = mt19937(rd());` line. Since that is in a parallel region, each thread gets its own seed.

Comment: you are almost correct because these codes are used to find the time taken and I found that my seed will be always used in each loop of parallel. Based on your suggestion, if I no  misunderstand, has that two seed replaced?
From
`unsigned seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();`
     
With these 
`#pragma omp parallel
 {
    stringstream res;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> percent(1, 100);
    res << "Thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << ": " << percent(rng) << "\n";
    cout << res.str();
  }`