# Move a random element from one vector to another vector

Tags: c++

At the moment i know how to move an element from one vector to the other. The issue is i want to move the element randomly instead of choosing the element. Code is below.

```
auto it = find(deck.begin(), deck.end(), 3);
    if (it != deck.end()) {
        player1.push_back(*it);
        deck.erase(it);
    }
```

This moves an element from one vector to the other but i have to choose the element by typing it in as you can see from the number three. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this randomly.

Comment: Look up how to get a random number in C++?

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly"? What elements to you want to remove?

Comment: Might be a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942273/how-to-get-a-random-element-from-a-c-container

Comment: Instead, consider shuffling the vector and always taking the last element.

Comment: there is a deck vector which has numbers 1 to 10. I want to move one of them numbers to another vector without me specifying which number

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you i never thought of that, that might just work

Comment: Take a look at this question : [How to shuffle a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks this should work perfectly.